# echo command color not working

Tags: bash, macos, colors, echo

I have a code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

COLOR_REST='\e[0m'
COLOR_GREEN='\e[0;32m'
echo -e "${COLOR_GREEN}OK${COLOR_REST}"
```

When I copy and paste the code into my iTerm, it displays `OK` in the color of green.

[image]

However, when I store the code in a file named `testColor.sh`, and execute `./testColor.sh`. It displays `\e[0;32mOK\e[0m` on my screen.

Why doesn't it display `OK` with green?

I've also tried `bash testColor.sh`, and `sh testColor.sh`. Both fail to display the text in green.

Another thing I feel strange is that I don't see the `-e` option in the BSD General Commands Manual in `man echo`.

I'm using macOS High Sierra as my operating system.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use

```
#!/bin/bash

COLOR_REST="$(tput sgr0)"
COLOR_GREEN="$(tput setaf 2)"
printf '%s%s%s\n' $COLOR_GREEN 'OK' $COLOR_REST
```

which uses printf to avoid `echo` options and `tput` to be portable across different terminals.

Comment: [This article](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/terminalcodes) says that we should `tput` instead of the ANSI codes directly.

Comment: Another [article](https://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) says that `\e`, `\033`, and `\x1B` represent the *Escape character* in bash. Maybe my `echo` command doesn't support `\e`.

Answer (score 5):

Using `printf` instead of `echo` should work in any POSIX compliant shell. I tried this in High Sierra with the default terminal and it didn't work (there weren't any extended options, just `-n`).

As for an explanation, I haven't used iTerm so I'm not completely sure, but could be a different `echo` implementation by iTerm, which would cause the flag to work only when using iTerm itself, not /bin/bash. Notice that in the man page for `echo`, it says

> NOTE: your shell may have its own version of echo, which usually supersedes the version described here. Please refer to your shell's documentation for details about the options it supports.

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of this syntax:

```
echo $'\e[31mRED\e[0m'
```

The `$'...'` notation causes the shell to honor escape codes e.g. `\t`, `\n`, `\e`.

This seems to work in bash, ksh, zsh, and sh -- yes, on MacOS.

The problem seems to be that Darwin's BSD-era `/bin/echo` does not actually accept `-e` argument at all. The `zsh` in recent versions of MacOS has a builtin `echo` that *does* take `-e`, but that's obviously  not portable to other shells unless you want to run every shell script with `zsh.`